# Custom AuthorizationRedirectStrategy in OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am using Keycloak version 22, Springboot 3.1
I would like to intercept the Keycloak URL before the request reach Keycloak.
Anyone has an example on how to do that using OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter ?
Any help please.
Thanks

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you want to do? You may need a custom OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver, but it's hard to say without more detail.

Comment: @jzheaux thanks for the note. I am trying to intercept the URL so that I can append the ui_locales to the URL. Basically I would like to modify the Authorization Redirect Strategy in a filter. 
So far I have a customer filter that extends OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter and in there inside the doFilterInternal() function I check if the URL contains "/auth/realms" if yes then I can add the "ui_locales". So the problem is so far I was not able to capture the Keycloak URL that contains "/auth/realms"... 
I hope it is clearer now. Thanks